# Jasmine deletes AngularJS controller instance between specs?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am trying to write unit tests for the AngularJS application. Below is a pretty standard test template, which works fine:

```
describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function () {
  var MainCtrl, scope;
  beforeEach(function() { // <-- what if I remove this
    module('watcomApp');
    inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
    $scope: scope,
      });
    });
  }); // <-- and this

  it('some spec', function () {
    expect(scope.data).toEqual('something');
  });
});
```

However if I try to reuse the current state of controller and remove **beforeEach:**

```
describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function () {
  var MainCtrl, scope;
  module('watcomApp');
  inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
  ...
```

it stops working because **scope.data** becomes undefined.
The question is: what happens to scope? I expect it to persist between specs since it's global.

Comment: reusing data between tests is usually *not* desired behaviour.  If you have a similar state that you want for two different tests, then you should build it up in the `beforeEach` for both tests.  If you change one test, you don't want to break another (that depends on the state the first set).

Comment: I have to admit that you are right. But the question remains, at least for the educational purpose :) I don't understand what's going on behind the scene with the scope variable.